# MySQL - Issue with Key Efficiency 100%

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL Administrator tool to monitor the health of MySQL server. Whenever I run a lengthy JOIN query, I realized the Key Efficiency Graph shots up to 100% all the time. I do some read up and found out that the higher the Key Efficiency, mean the index cache is fully utilized.

The problem is when Key Efficiency hits 100%, my other queries will run very slow or seems cannot run at all.

These are my buffer settings. I'm using mostly InnoDB. MySQL version 5.0.77.

```
| bdb_log_buffer_size           | 262144     |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size       | 8388608    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_awe_mem_mb | 0          |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size       | 1073741824 |
| innodb_log_buffer_size        | 1048576    |
| join_buffer_size              | 20971520   |
| key_buffer_size               | 1073741824 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size       | 33554432   |
| net_buffer_length             | 16384      |
| preload_buffer_size           | 32768      |
| read_buffer_size              | 20971520   |
| read_rnd_buffer_size          | 4194304    |
| sort_buffer_size              | 20971520   |
```

Comment: This question might suit http://dba.stackexchange.com better - you'll probably get more relevant and quick answers there.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion will HELP also.

REMOVE the following list so DEFAULTS can support your effort from [mysqld] section of my.cnf/.ini

- `sort_buffer_size`
- `read_buffer_size`
- `read_rnd_buffer_size`
- `join_buffer_size`

  to improve(reduce) response time.

Why would you intentionally read 20M of read_buffer_size data when you could get the data you need with the DEFAULT of 128K ?